# inset_element from patchwork is flipping the inset upside down

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I'm trying to use `patchwork`'s `inset_element` function to make a map with an inset. I've toyed with the placement and various other values and am happy with where my inset has been placed, but the inset map is getting flipped upside down.

Now, I've created a reproducible example using figures instead of maps made by `geom_sf`, and it reproduces the same behavior:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("patchwork")

set.seed(0922023)

a <- rnorm(1000)
b <- rnorm(1000)
c <- rnorm(1000)
d <- c + rnorm(1000)

df <- cbind.data.frame(a, b, c, d)

plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_point()

plot1

plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = c, y = d)) +
  geom_point()

plot2

inset <- inset_element(
  plot1,
  left = 0.7,
  bottom = 1,
  right = 1,
  top = 0.7
)

combined_plot <- plot2 + inset

combined_plot
```

The first plot looks like this:

[image: First plot example]

The second plot looks like this:

[image: Second plot example]

Putting them together with patchwork places the first plot where I want it to be, but flips it upside down!

[image: Patchwork inset is flipped upside down]

Now, these plots aren't pretty because I'm just making a minimum working example, but when I do this with my actual data (and the placement looks nice), I get the same error. Here's the kicker: if I wanted to, I could flip `plot1` and have it go into the inset upside down so it *ends up* right-side up, but there are two issues with this.

1. My actual example being a map means it's non-trivial to flip upside down.
2. It seems like in principle this shouldn't be happening at all, and while that workaround might work, it doesn't really get at the underlying problem.

I've tried messing with the `top` and `bottom` arguments of `inset_element`. For example, the following code puts the plot right-side-up, but in the bottom-right corner. I need it to be in the top-left corner.

```
# alternative
inset <- inset_element(
  plot1,
  left = 0.7,
  bottom = 0,
  right = 1,
  top = 0.3
)

combined_plot <- plot2 + inset

combined_plot
```

[image: Alternative patchwork inset is right-side-up, but not in the correct position]

Maybe I'm just not understanding the arguments of `inset_element` correctly, but I haven't found helpful information online to fix this. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bottom=` and `top=` are based on the bottom of the plot, not the top. If you swap so that `bottom=0.7` and `top=1`, you get more appropriate results.

```r
inset <- inset_element(
  plot1,
  left = 0.7,
  bottom = 0.7,
  right = 1,
  top = 1
)
plot2 + inset
```

[image: combined inset plot]

being the combination of `plot2`

[image: plot2]

and `plot1`

[image: plot1]

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't believe I tried so many different things but didn't realize this intuitive solution. Much appreciated.